# simple javascript, functions in objects

Tags: javascript, function

```
var rooms = {
bedroom: {
    info: "A dusty bed lies sideways in the midle of the room";

    north: function (  ) {
        //this function returns an error
    }
}
};
```

I cant work out why this returns an unexpected identifier

-- edit
thanks another question

in javascript the good parts he has

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0;
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```

is this different to what I am doing?

Comment: @fxmile - Looks like a mistake in the book. Is it on page 28 (or close by)? Something similar is listed in the [errata for the book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517748) for that page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One should use a `,` inside of object literals when defining keys and values to separate them, not `;`.

```
var o = { name: 'john', age: 13 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
the room";
```

There should be `,`, not `;`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, it looks there is a typo in the book.

The incorrect example is:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0;
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```

The correct example is:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0, 
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```

Note the comma on the line `value: 0,`.

As others have mentioned, the comma should be used (instead of the semicolon) for object literals.